# Magento using Postgres?

Tags: magento-enterprise, database

I'm trying to use Postgres instead of the default MySQL setup. I understand that Magento 2 should support Postgres out of the box (once it is released). From the looks of it there is a layer of abstraction between the view and the data layer, using something like Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection. I'm more curious whether there is a current solution either Enterprise or Community 1.7+.

**--EDIT--**
Heres an update I got from Alan at Magento; they'll most likely want to move forward with eventually supporting multiple RDBMS' but it'll most likely be through the support of the Doctrine ORM (or some other ORM). I don't think they'll release this by the GA of M2 though.

Answer (score 2):

Support for anything other than MySQL is not planned as of now and based on my understanding it is not easy to support anything else right now. You would have to change at least all installation schema, some data types and more.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Enterprise, using something other than MySQL would be unsupported, which would negate one of the advantages of Enterprise.

Regarding Community, there hasn't much done with Postgres, and it looks like it would be a big tasks to support it. If you must have Postgresql, give Bitcommerce a look. It is the only feature complete eCommerce solution with total Postgres support.

https://github.com/bitweaver/bitcommerce

Comment: Bitcommerce is basically a fork of the Magento/Zen framework, correct? Would it be possible to simply overwrite the core files/functions that deal with the data layer (using the local directory). Similar to what some extensions do.

Comment: I'm sure it is possible, but by the fact it hasn't already been done, I'm guessing it is a big job :(

Comment: I've heard the argument that because of the modular nature, Magento will support using any SQL database engine, that it's a simple rewrite. And tried to follow several of these projects. The sound of chirping crickets followed on every one so it's got hidden gotchas somewhere. And I'll believe the Magento 2 thing when I can stick my fingers through the holes in its hands.

Comment: There is way too much to do to make Postgres work, I imagine for M2 and certainly for M1. @FiascoLabs - see you in two weeks during the M2 beta launch :-)

Comment: Heres an update I got from Alan at Magento; they'll most likely want to move forward with eventually supporting multiple RDBMS' but it'll most likely be through the support of the Doctrine ORM (or some other ORM). I don't think they'll release this by the GA of M2 though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Magento is still capable of running on Postgres.
I've managed to run homepage, category, product pages.
It was running on other databases back in 2011, even in production. 
Anyway, I am filling up [Magento Postgres Adapter](https://github.com/kirmorozov/mage-postgres-compatibility) with compatible changes to the core.

I feel that it is possible to get it to beta state by end of 2021.